# Call [].reverse on a string

Tags: javascript

Why does

```
[].reverse.call("string");
```

fails (error in both firefox and ie, returns the original string in chrome) while calling all other arrays methods on a string work ?

```
>>> [].splice.call("string",3)
["i", "n", "g"]
>>> [].map.call("string",function (a) {return a +a;} )
["ss", "tt", "rr", "ii", "nn", "gg"]
```

Comment: _"all other array methods"_ - does `.sort()` work? For the ones that do work, do they work in all browsers? (I would guess they'd fail for older browsers that haven't implemented array-style `[]` index notation for strings, though I haven't tested it.)

Comment: @nnnnnn sort does not work for the same very reason

Comment: @Hai: FYI, `.splice()` doesn't really work. Chrome is kind enough to give you the returned value, but if you reference the original string before splicing it, you'll find that it isn't modified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `.reverse()` modifies an Array, and strings are immutable.

---

You could borrow `Array.prototype.slice` to convert to an Array, then reverse and join it.

```
var s = "string";

var s2 = [].slice.call(s).reverse().join('');
```

Just be aware that in older versions of IE, you can't manipulate a string like an Array.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Thanks, but now I've gone and screwed up your complement. :)

Comment: @amnotiam, i'm too late then, sorry.

Comment: Actually only non-mutation `array` methods can apply on `string` according to  https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md

Answer (score 5):

The following technique (or similar) is commonly used to reverse a string in JavaScript:

```
// Don’t use this!
var naiveReverse = function(string) {
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

In fact, all the answers posted so far are a variation of this pattern. However, there are some problems with this solution. For example:

```
naiveReverse('foo  bar');
// → 'rab �� oof'
// Where did the `` symbol go? Whoops!
```

If you’re wondering why this happens, [read up on JavaScript’s internal character encoding](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding). (TL;DR:  is an astral symbol, and JavaScript exposes it as two separate code units.)

But there’s more:

```
// To see which symbols are being used here, check:
// http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1ma%C3%B1ana%20man%CC%83ana
naiveReverse('mañana mañana');
// → 'anãnam anañam'
// Wait, so now the tilde is applied to the `a` instead of the `n`? WAT.
```

A good string to test string reverse implementations is [the following](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1foo%20%F0%9D%8C%86%20bar%20ma%C3%B1ana%20man%CC%83ana):

```
'foo  bar mañana mañana'
```

Why? Because it contains an astral symbol () (which are [represented by surrogate pairs in JavaScript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-pairs)) and a combining mark (the `ñ` in the last `mañana` actually consists of two symbols: U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N and U+0303 COMBINING TILDE).

The order in which surrogate pairs appear cannot be reversed, else the astral symbol won’t show up anymore in the ‘reversed’ string. That’s why you saw those `��` marks in the output for the previous example.

Combining marks always get applied to the previous symbol, so you have to treat both the main symbol (U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N) as the combining mark (U+0303 COMBINING TILDE) as a whole. Reversing their order will cause the combining mark to be paired with another symbol in the string. That’s why the example output had `ã` instead of `ñ`.

Hopefully, this explains why all the answers posted so far are **wrong**.

---

To answer your initial question — *how to [properly] reverse a string in JavaScript* —, I’ve written a small JavaScript library that is capable of Unicode-aware string reversal. It doesn’t have any of the issues I just mentioned. The library is called [**Esrever**](http://mths.be/esrever); its code is on GitHub, and it works in pretty much any JavaScript environment. It comes with a shell utility/binary, so you can easily reverse strings from your terminal if you want.

```
var input = 'foo  bar mañana mañana';
esrever.reverse(input);
// → 'anañam anañam rab  oof'
```

Answer (score 4):

See @am not i am's answer for why it doesn't work. However, if you want to know how to accomplish this, convert it to an array first:

```
"string".split('').reverse().join(''); // "gnirts"
```

Comment: +1 `.split()` will be a more browser compatible array conversion than `[].slice()`.